# Haskell: Call a function with each element in a list

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I am making a sudoku solving program and I have a `potentialNbrsAt` function that gets the numbers that could be at position x y.

Now, I am trying to get the intersect of each lists of potential numbers in a column. Something like the `onlyOnePlaceForNbrInCol` function bellow.

Code:

```
potentialNbrsAt :: Int -> Int -> Sudoku -> [Int]
potentialNbrsAt x y sudoku = intersect rowMissingNbrs $ intersect colMissingNbrs sqrMissingNbrs
                where rowMissingNbrs = getMissingNbrs $ getRow y sudoku
                      colMissingNbrs = getMissingNbrs $ getCol x sudoku
                      sqrMissingNbrs = getMissingNbrs $ getSquare squareIndex sudoku
                      squareIndex    = 3 * (y `div` 3) + (x `div` 3)

onlyOnePlaceForNbrInCol :: Int -> Int -> Sudoku -> Bool
onlyOnePlaceForNbrInCol colIndex nbr sudoku = -- What goes here? Some pointers please???
```

I think onlyOnePlaceForNbrInCol should, at some point, call potentialNbrsAt with each numbers from 0 to 8 as an argument for y. Telling me how to do this would greatly help.

Comment: PS: whenenver the number 9, or the `div` operator,  occur in a Sudoku solver, it shows insufficient modelling: the grid does not have two dimensions (9x9), but four (3x3x3x3). In German, "die Anschauung ist auch oft der Feind des Verständnisses."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `[ potentialNbrsAt x y sudoku | y <- [0..8] ]` ? This gives you a list of all the results for such values of `y`.

Comment: I did not expect it could be so easy. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

So you're trying to determine whether [all](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=all) of the numbers `[0..8]` fulfill a given predicate.